# A simple drawer using CSS3 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a simple drawer using CSS3 and jQuery that works with hover and click. It seems to be working fine but surely there's a simpler way of writing the code.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/73MpU/

```
$("#bottom-page").click(function () {
    $("#top-page").addClass("push");
});

$("#bottom-page").mouseover(function () {
    $("#top-page").addClass("nudge-right");
});

$("#bottom-page").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#top-page").removeClass("nudge-right");
});

$("#top-page").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("push");
    $(this).removeClass("nudge-left");
});

$("#top-page").mouseover(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("push")) {
        $(this).addClass("nudge-left");
    }
});

$("#top-page").mouseleave(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("push")) {
        $(this).removeClass("nudge-left");
    }
});
```

So, I simplified my code a bit. Is this valid?

**Edit**:

```
$("#bottom-page").hover(function () {
    $("#top-page:not(.push)").toggleClass("nudge-right");
});

$("#bottom-page").click(function () {
    $("#top-page:not(.push)").removeClass("nudge-right");
    $("#top-page:not(.push)").addClass("push");
});

$("#top-page").hover(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("push")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("nudge-left");
    }
});

$("#top-page").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("push")) {
        $(this).removeClass("push nudge-left");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to group the `toggleClass` inside one `.hover`, like this:

```
var $top=$("#top-page");             //save #top-page in $top var

$("#bottom-page").click(function () {
    $top.addClass("push");
}).hover(function(){                 //chain .hover to #bottom-page
    $top.toggleClass("nudge-right");
    if ($top.hasClass("push")) {     //if $top has the .push class then toggle .nudge-left
        $top.toggleClass("nudge-left");
    }
});    

$top.click(function () {             //on $top click remove the .push and .nudege-left class
    $top.removeClass("push nudge-left");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73MpU/1/